# What exit code values does plink.exe return?

Tags: putty, plink

I'm using the PuTTY utility `plink.exe` to run remote commands, and it's returning exit code 2. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

The `plink.exe` does not return 2 on its own.

It returns 1 on error.

When it successfully executes a remote command, it returns an exit code of the remote command. So it must be the remote command that returns the 2.